# jsp and .equals and .trim() null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsp

this might be a pretty stupid question, im trying to figure out why im getting a null exception, please help.

```
String username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");

if (!username.equals("ADMIN")) {
   request.setAttribute("Error", "You are not the admin");
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginPage.jsp");
   rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

im trying to get the jsp to check whether the username equals "ADMIN", if it doesnt equal admin then it will give an error and then request the login page.

but i get a null pointer exception for line:

```
if (!username.equals("ADMIN")) {
```

thanks

Comment: Looks like you don't have an attribute in session called `username`. Maybe you're confusing the session attribute with a request parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats because `username` is null

Best practice is to say `if (!"ADMIN".equals(username))`

Since a constant String "ADMIN" is a non-null value, invoking `equals()` on it will not cause any error and will be safe

OR do a null check on `username` before comparing:

```
if (username != null && !username.equals("ADMIN"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `username` is null, i.e. not stored in the session. If using an IDE like Eclipse, you can put a breakpoint in, hover over the term with your mouse, and see what is null.